# Updating Debian Linux via crontab

Tags: linux, debian, crontab

I am trying to have my Raspberry Pi do its own update weekly with the following command

Not certain which one to use because running the command with su root fails on my terminal.

59 2 * * 1 root apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade -y > /home/pi/update.log

59 2 * * 1 su root -c "apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade -y" > /home/pi/update.log

Comment: Better use the specialized tool for this: [`unattended-upgrades`](https://manpages.debian.org/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.8). It will handle more cases than one command in crontab.

Comment: Thank you!    still uses crontab, I don't see an advantage..This script is the backend for the APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade option and designed to be run from cron (e.g. via /etc/cron.daily/apt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention crontab, by which I assume you mean `/etc/crontab` as opposed to the `crontab` for an individual user (also possible, but answer is slightly different). `/etc/crontab` has the format,

```
min hour day-of-month month day-of-week user  command
```

so your 2nd proposed line would run the *command* `root ...` as the user `su` which isn't what you want: `apt-get` needs to run as `root`. We'll sort out the 'command' part soon, but the rest will look like this - based on your specified time+day,

```
59 2 * * 1 root command
```

Since 'command' will be running as root with the above line, there's no need to use `sudo`. I concur with A.B's suggestion of using `unattended-upgrade` as being `cron`-friendly and already having a log file target so no need to fiddle around with redirecting output to a file etc. Thus you end up with,

```
59 2 * * 1 root unattended-upgrade
```

for your more bare-metal approach you'd have instead (note that I've removed the unnecessary `sudo` as explained above) (untested),

```
59 2 * * 1 root (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y) > /home/pi/update.log
```

I've also added parentheses to execute both commands in one shell for the output of *both* commands to be sent to your specified log file.

Comment: Perfekt, thank you!